# CSS 2 background images when 1 finish 2 start

Tags: html, css, background

I need have 2 background images in body, 1 height from to 500px an dsecond from 500px to auto;

```
body{
background: url("../img/bg.png")repeat-x left top; 
background:  url("../img/bg-color.png") repeat left top;}
```

My code display only second image, how to fix code that will be displayed 2 images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant have multiples images as background, unless you are using CSS3. In case that's what you are going for, the multiple images should be declared in the same like, like this:

```
background-image: url("file1.jpg"), url("file2.jpg");
```

If you dont want to use CSS3, you will need to use different DOM elements, one for each image.